Camel Rest DLS OpenAPI - common processing
In my Route Builder i create a rest endpont using Rest DSL and Contract First aproach.
rest()
 .openapi()
 .specification("my-open-api.json");

I wonder if it is possible to do some common processing (a processor or a to route) before sending to the individual direct routes.
In particular I want to do the authorization check that is common for all of them.
